# onclick confirm function with different text from array

Tags: php, javascript

I am having an issue with attempting to show different confirm text from an array when using a hyperlink. The text always ends up being from the last confirmation text in the array. I have seen 2 examples on this forum using a function() in a function but I was not able to get this working from viewing the examples.

Here is my code:

```
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">         
        function getDetails(message)
        {           
            if (confirm(message))
                return true;
            else
            {                   
                var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

                for(i=0;i<links.length;i++) 
                    links[i].href = item_NoLink;
            }           
        }
    </script>';

foreach ($items as $item)
{
    $link = 'http://test_url/mytest.php;report='. $item['id'];

            echo '
            <script type="text/javascript">                 
                var item_detail = ', json_encode($item['reported_spam']['detail']),'
                var item_NoLink = ', json_encode('http://test_url/mytest.php;'),'                   
            </script>
                <a id="mylink[]" onclick="getDetails(item_detail);" href="'.$link.'" style="text-decoration:none;">
                    <img id="myImage" alt="" src="http://test_url/images/reported.gif" title="'.$item['reported_spam']['title'].'" style="position:relative;border=0px;vertical-align:middle;right:5px;" />
                </a>';

}
```

Thanks.

---

Edit: I figured it out.

@Grant Zhu: Arrays are not written like that in php and one can progress to the next key just using the empty square brackets. You were correct as I did make an err for the image id array and the js variables. Also for php when using single quotes inside echo with single quotes one must use the backslash (unless using php again).

I got it working as such:

```
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">   
    var item_NoLink = ', json_encode('http://test_url/mytest.php;'),'         
    function getDetails(message)
    {           
        if (confirm(message))
            return true;
        else
        {                   
            var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

            for(i=0;i<links.length;i++) 
                links[i].href = item_NoLink;
        }           
    }
</script>';

foreach ($items as $item)
{
    $link = 'http://test_url/mytest.php?report='. $item['id'];

        echo '            
            <a id="mylink[]" onclick="getDetails(\'',$item['reported_spam']['detail'],'\');" href="'.$link.'" style="text-decoration:none;">
                <img id="myImage[]" alt="" src="http://test_url/images/reported.gif" title="'.$item['reported_spam']['title'].'" style="position:relative;border=0px;vertical-align:middle;right:5px;" />
            </a>';

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$link = 'http://test_url/mytest.php;report='. $item['id'];
```

this code is weird , I think your code might be

```
$link = 'http://test_url/mytest.php?report='. $item['id'];
```

Comment: I changed the url's for this question. My issue is only that I can not seem to get the specific message from $item['reported_spam']['detail'] from the array for each link to appear in the confirm text. What occurs is the detail text from the last key of the array always shows for every link for confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the javascript generated and you will find there're multiple declarations of item_detail and item_NoLink. That means you assign the values to the same variables again and again. Of course, the last assignment takes effect in the end.

You can put the detail text directly in the getDetails function. Make sure the text is quoted by '. And you'd better make the id of `<a>` and `<img>` unique because that's what id means. I'm not familiar with PHP, check the syntax below if it's correct.

```
foreach ($items as $item)
{
    $link = 'http://test_url/mytest.php;report='. $item['id'];

            echo '
                <a id="mylink$item['id']" onclick="getDetails(', json_encode($item['reported_spam']['detail']),');" href="'.$link.'" style="text-decoration:none;">
                    <img id="myImage$item['id']" alt="" src="http://test_url/images/reported.gif" title="'.$item['reported_spam']['title'].'" style="position:relative;border=0px;vertical-align:middle;right:5px;" />
                </a>';

}
```

Comment: I figured this out & the answer is in the original post.

Comment: @snoop_dog As I said, I'm not familiar with PHP, the code above is just an idea how the javascript should be embeded in your code. If my anwser helps you, you should give a upvote and accept :)

Comment: I do not seem to have enough reputation points to award people with merit as far as I can tell. As for the check mark, I am not going to flag someone's answer as correct when it contains error in the code. Also your answer put me on the right track but was not 100% correct markup. Thank you for that but imo do not demand merit, people will award you when appropriate and be glad to get a polite thank you.

Comment: @snoop_dog IMO, I think idea is more important. As I have said above, I'm not familiar with PHP and, in fact, this is a javascript problem but not a PHP problem. So people can regard the PHP part as pseudo-code because the syntax doesn't matter at all. The key point of your problem is not syntax. You can't blame a correct answer just because it misses a comma, right?   I'm not asking for reputations as I don't care. But I do think your judge of correct answer is a bit too strict.